# autoComplete (jquery.auto-complete.js) categories with label metadata

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am able to do basic labels and categories using

> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

but my need without using

> $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {});

how i am able to do this using

> jQuery( ".class" ).autoComplete({ });
>
> https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html

However, I was wondering if its possible to attach some **metadata** with label. For example...

```
"[{ label: \"labelname1\", category: \"cat1\" },{ label: \"labelname2\", category: \"cat1\" },
  { label: \"labelname3\", category: \"cat2\" },{ label: \"labelname4\", category: \"cat2\" },
  { label: \"labelname5\", category: \"cat2\" },
  ];"
```

I want to something like :

cat1

-labelname1

-labelname2

cat2

-labelname3

-labelname4

-labelname5

Note: only use by jQuery( ".class" ).autoComplete({ });

ref : > https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess is this you are looking for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  $( ".class" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ { label: "labelname1", category: "cat1" }, { label: "labelname2", category: "cat2" }, { label: "labelname3", category: "cat3" } ],
  select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".class" ).val( ui.item.label );

            return false;
        }
})
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li>" )
                .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.category + "<br>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };

 });
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Ops, sorry. I will update my answer. I forgot to put a select function. I already tested and it's working

Comment: If you want to select just a label, you  change the append:                 .append(  item.category + "<br><a>" + item.label + "</a>" )

Comment: but do not use autocomplete({}); function.

Comment: i have use see this ref  https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html

Comment: how i am able to do this using
jQuery( ".class" ).autoComplete({ });
https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html

note .autoComplete (C is capital ) haha